# SimpleExpandableListAdapter sections titles

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I implemented my `SimpleExpandableListAdapter`, and I'm trying to customize the section titles. To do this I pass to the [constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleExpandableListAdapter.html#SimpleExpandableListAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20java.util.List%3C?%20extends%20java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20?%3E%3E,%20int,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d,%20int%5b%5d,%20java.util.List%3C?%20extends%20java.util.List%3C?%20extends%20java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20?%3E%3E%3E,%20int,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d,%20int%5b%5d%29) the id of a custom `TextView` for the *groupTo* parameter:

```
    setListAdapter( new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(this,
                                                    groupsData, 
                                                    android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,
                                                    new String[]{SECTION}, 
                                                    new int[]{R.id.list_group_title}, 
                                                    innerData,
                                                    0, 
                                                    null, 
                                                    new int[]{}){ /*my code here*/ });

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list_group_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20dip" />
```

Problem is, nothing is showing up! The whole thing is blank, as if the view wasn't there.
Any idea on why, or any link I could read up to solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    MyAdapter ma = new MyAdapter(this,groupsData,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,new String[]{SECTION}, new int[]{R.layout.list_group_title},innerData,0,null,new int[]{});
    setListAdapter(ma);


    private static class MyAdapter extends SimpleExpandableListAdapter
    {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
            int title;

            public MyAdapter(Context context,List<? extends Map<String, ?>> groupData,int groupLayout,String[ ] groupFrom,int[ ] groupTo,List<? extends List<? extends Map<String, ?>>> childData,int childLayout,String[ ] childFrom, int[ ] childTo)
            {           
                super(context,groupData,groupLayout,groupFrom,groupTo,childData,childLayout,childFrom,childTo);
                title = groupTo[0];
                layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            }
            @Override
            public View getGroupView(int groupPosition,boolean isExpanded,View convertView,ViewGroup parent)
            {
                return (TextView)layoutInflater.inflate(title,null);
            }
    }
```

Inflating it in `getGroupView` does the trick. Still, I don't understand why it is not passed automatically to the `super` constructor.